# stop laptop from going to sleep when closed?

Tags: suspend, laptop

stop laptop from going to sleep when closed? i trid to search it from https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stop+laptop+from+going+to+sleep+when+closed+ubuntu&t=canonical&ia=qa&iax=qa and the first command doesent work: up sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf but i get error `sudo: gedit: command not found`

Comment: What's your Ubuntu Version?

Comment: It's not such complicated as in your provided link.. Recent version of Ubuntu's its pretty easy.

Comment: but it tells me sudo gedit: command not found

Comment: What's your Ubuntu Version?

Comment: xubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Oh sorry. For Xubuntu no such thing like gnome tweaks know..

Comment: What is your default text editor? I think it's `mousepad` so change gedit with mousepad in that command.. `sudo -H mousepad /etc/systemd/logind.conf`

Comment: Have you tried all the options in power manager